# Documentation of immutability of Java wrapper classes

Tags: java, immutability

It is well-known that the type wrappers such as `Integer`, `Double`, `Boolean` are immutable. However, I was unable to find this documented in the official API documentation, e.g., https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html. I also looked in the source code files, and did *not* find this stated in the comments. (The comments in the source code for `String`, on the other hand, does mention its immutability.)

Is this because:
- it's documented elsewhere (if so, where?),
- this fact is too "well-known", or
- the developer is expected to read the implementation of the wrappers and figure out whether the wrapper is immutable or not?

Comment: Well none of those classes have any mutators...unlike for `String.concat()` you might imagine that it modifies the `String` instead of returning the new concatenated one.

Comment: "the developer is expected to read the implementation" No, you should never be expected to do so. But you can infer it from the *documentation* (as in, it's `final`, and there are no setters).

Comment: @AndyTurner Depends what you mean by immutable. Immutability is often discussed in context of thread-safety, which is dependent on implementation details such as `final` fields.

Comment: @shmosel good point!

Comment: @shmosel immutabilty in the context of class interfaces is well-defined (by Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html, part of the OCA exam as well). Other contexts may use the same term, but this is the context here. I fully agree with AndyTurner's statement. Immutability is a property of a class' interface and does not really need to be documented as such.

Comment: @daniu If you look at that very page, you'll see *Immutable objects... cannot be corrupted by thread interference **or observed in an inconsistent state.*** This only holds true when the internals are implemented correctly. It does seem to conflict with the initial statement on the page, but I wouldn't consider the Oracle tutorial an authoritative source to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth consideration that immutable can mean two things:

a) that if you pass this value somwhere it can't be mutated.

b) "a" and that it can be safely used in multithreaded environment

ad A) There are classes that are just immutable but not thread safe, they are good to be used with setters/getters and to be keys in HashMap - these ones with no mutators, with all fields private but without all fields final or volatile.

ad B) There are classes that are immutable and thread safe - these without mutators and with all fields private and final or volatile.

Classes that are thread safe are often described as so in the documentation or even by name, of course some classes can be immutable and/or thread safe but not strictly documented as so. For example the `String` class is documented to be "constant", but there is no information about thread safety - there is only one enigmatic statement "Because String objects are immutable they can be shared" but I think it means something different than ...shared with other threads. We just know the properties of popular classes, but I agree that these properties should be clearly documented. Unfortunatelly in real life they aren't. So the only way to know if class is immutable is to check the documentation and if there is not enough  information, then check the implemetation and ask the author if He plans to make the class mutable in the future. This topic is considered in a book Java Concurrency in Practice, and the author suggest to use two annotations to denote that something is `@ThreadSafe` and/or `@Immutable` but unfortunatelly this isn't a common practice yet.

Answer (score 0):

The boxed wrappers are "immutable" because they're virtually 
interchangeable syntactically with the literal types they wrap. For example `boolean` is immutable:

```
boolean x = false;
x.flip();  // not implemented
```

Native types in most programming languages are immutable. Therefore, by the wrapper contract,

```
Boolean x = false;
x.mutate(/* ??? */);
```

is not defined either.